# Stiefel Whitney class and embedding problem.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a problem, reading the book "Characteristic classes".

In the page 120, Corollary 11.4 is that

If $M = M^n$ is smoothly embedded as a closed subset of the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, then $w_k(v^k)= 0$. In the oriented case $e(v^k) = 0$.

As a remark, the open Moebius band can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
But it cannot be embedded as a closed subset, since the associated Stiefel-Whitney class $\overline{w_1}(\tau)$ is non-zero.

The associated Stiefel-Whitney class $\overline{w_1}(\tau)$ is the inverse of the Stiefel-Whitney class of the tangent bundle.

Buy why is the $\overline{w_1}(\tau)$ nonzero?

I feel that I can find the fact before this page. But I can not yet.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smooth manifold is orientable if and only if $w_1(\tau)=0$. We know the Möbius band is not orientable, so that it has nonzero $w_1$; since $H^k(M;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)=0$ for $k>1$, we write $w(M)=(1+w_1)$, with $w_1$ nonzero. Then $w$'s inverse is $1-w_1$, as $w_1^2=0$.